# What is the word for a love of ignorance, or a distaste of knowledge?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or short phrase that encapsulates the desire to eschew new knowledge, whether it be due to a fear of change or possibly a fear of science or research as a whole.

An example might be a group of people looking to have their congressional representative allocate money elsewhere as opposed to scientific endeavors. They may claim that the "elsewhere" is of a higher priority or for the greater good, but they may really be acting out of ________ or because the group is a group of _________(s).

This example is not all-inclusive.

**edit:**
There's a word or phrase I'm trying to think of that almost implies a sort of smugness.. A "my ignorance is better than your knowledge" kind of attitude.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119199/word-for-someone-who-is-ignorant-and-proud

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Anti-intellectualism** is a handy (and self-explanatory) term, particularly in American politics today. It has [great currency in the news media](https://www.google.com/search?q=anti-intellectualism&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2014%2Ccd_max%3A5%2F1%2F2015&tbm=nws) of late, largely with regard to situations such as the one described in your example.

Comment: ...or Luddite. Though it is usually used for anti-technology, it can also be used for reactionary scientific thinking.

Comment: @Mitch - Hey!!??  We Luddites know more than most people -- that's why we know how bad things are!

Comment: The irony being that the actual Luddite movement wasn't anti-tech, rather it was anti-exploitative labour employment. They broke a bunch of industrial equipment in protest and they caught the unfortunate misattribution as a result @Mitch

Comment: While I don't like the style of this word quite as much as `misosophy` or `philistine`, it definitely satisfies the definition (as I described it) with the most precision.

Answer (score 18):

There is a rare word ***misosophy*** defined as the hatred of wisdom or knowledge.

An example from OED:

> Much of modern philosophy is in fact not at all a ‘love of wisdom’ but a hatred of it so that it should appropriately be called ‘misosophy’.
>
> <sub>S. H. Nasr, *Ideals & Realities of Islam*, 1966</sub>

It is from the  ancient Greek *μισόσοϕος* hating wisdom ( < *μισο*- miso- *comb. form* + *-σοϕος* , combining form of *σοϕός* wise) + -y suffix. <sup>*[OED]*</sup>

Additionally, you can call the person a *misosophist*.

Another similar rare word is ***misogrammatist***, a person who hates letters or learning. [miso- *comb. form* + ancient Greek *γράμματα* ‘letters’, plural of *γράμμα* letter  + -ist *suffix*].<sup>*[OED]*</sup>

Comment: That doesn't have quite the connotation I'm thinking of, but it does satisfy the question. If no other closer answers turn up, I'll accept this one and consider a better wording for my question. Edited question for, perhaps, more clarity.

Comment: @Waterbagel: How about "sweet ignorance" ?

Comment: Good, much like `blissful ignorance` in relation to @Area's answer.. But that describes more of a state of being rather than a group.

Comment: @Waterbagel: I think you could say "blissfully ignorant people" also but it might be too cumbersome. There is  [*blissful ignorance effect*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blissful_ignorance_effect) along the same line.

Answer (score 10):

Not precisely opposed to *knowledge* or *intellectualism*, but a close relative nonetheless is ***philistinism***.

A ***philistine*** is one who is hostile or indifferent to culture and the arts. Adjective is *philistine* as in *a philistine government*.

This sense of *philistine* (no capital letter) arose as a result of a confrontation between town and gown in Jena (now in Germany), in the late 17th century; a sermon on the conflict quoted: 'the Philistines are upon you' (*Judges 16*). which led to an association between the townspeople and those hostile to culture. (Oxford Dictionary Online)

Comment: +1 Definitely a good word, and I look forward to using it as well. It's the right style of word I'm looking for, and if it had the connotation of opposing knowledge of well, it would be perfect. Thanks for bringing this one up.

Answer (score 4):

This one just applies to your second blank: "... or because the group is a group of [lowbrows](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lowbrow)."

> Noun  1.  lowbrow - a person who is uninterested in intellectual
>   pursuits

Most of the “lowbrows” that I’m unfortunately related to are quite smug and happy with their close-minded condition.
(I’d officially suggest ”pretentious lowbrow,” but mine take it as a complement.)

Answer (score 2):

You could coin a new word from the Greek roots: **gnosiphobia**. Failing that, you have the already known **"obscurantist"**.

Comment: Obscurantism is about hiding knowledge from others, not about fear of knowledge.

Comment: @Mitch: True, though I bet that in the heyday of 19th-century anti-clericalism it got used my way as well. I was distracted by an incoming mail while trying to retrieve another word from the back of my mind, why don't you have a go? I think it's the same vintage, the time of Huxley and Freud.

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to expressions, people in given situation might say

**[ignorance is bliss](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ignorance+is+bliss)** (dictionary.com)

> Not knowing something is often more comfortable than knowing it.
>
> Note : This proverb resembles “What you don't know cannot hurt you.” It figures in a passage from “On a Distant Prospect of Eton College,” by the eighteenth-century English poet Thomas Gray: “Where ignorance is bliss, / ‘Tis folly to be wise.’”

As in:

"I don't wanna know where the money came from. Like they say, ignorance is bliss."

Comment: That idiom is definitely on the right track, but I'm looking for something more like a noun or noun-phrase.. possibly an adjective that can be used to describe a group of people.

Answer (score 0):

"Misosophy" is just the word I need for a story I'm writing! I really like the "gnosiphobia" suggestion. Another word one might invent is ""philamathis", Greek for the love of ignorance. A group of such people might be "philamathics"? You could cover all possibilities with "philamathignosiphobia" or "gnosiphobiaphilamathis"...Or, my personal favorite, a word I invented to describe certain people: "phalocephalic" ("phallus" + "caphaly").A group would be "phalocephalists", suffering from phalocephalitis, perhaps, since this sort of thinking/behavior tends to be contagious. I can call someone a phalocephalic in the most polite or uptight company, and never be accused of using "dirty words"....

Answer (score 0):

In trying to justify "philamathics", I came across "agnatology" which sounds like your subject area. That led me to "negationism" but that feels more like official disinformation, not the smugness implied in your need.

More searching led me to "misology", the hatred of reason, argument, or enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

It has been touched upon and gotten near the mark, I'm pretty sure the common term (or at least the one I hear all the time) is *blissful ignorance*.

> **Blissful Ignorance** - unawareness or inexperience of something unpleasant

*Collins Dictionary*

Answer (score -3):

This feels a bit like a shotgun approach, but:

- *conservatives* (in the literal sense) would oppose because the new might not keep all the benefits of the old,
- *traditionalists* would oppose because we've never done it that way (there's a slight undercurrent of smugness here, but also a slightly negative connotation)
- *neophobes* are simply afraid of the new, no smugness here, (and frankly, is that even a proper word?),
- *myopic*, *blinkered* or *short-sighted* people would oppose because they do not value a benefit that is long-term or in other fields,
- *luddites* in particular oppose industrialization and technology.

(I have a sense that *petit bourgeois* could go in here, but that's probably a false friend with *Kleinbürgertum*, *Spießertum* and *Biedermeier*, which have a stronger socio-political connotation in German than their counterparts)