# The Converse of Philosophy

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, antonyms, philosophy

The etymology of philosophy is "love of wisdom" (simplified)... So what would the word be that defines the converse of "love of wisdom"?

Since it is not definitively established what the converse of Philosophy is...

"To loathe/hate wisdom" or "to be apathetic of wisdom"... I think are good starting points...

I am thinking that the proper term is likely to include -sophia for continuity/context...

It would be nice to get suggestions that you have actually tried to pronounce out loud...

Sorry for the lack of tags, but I just signed up, and you must have enough rep points to use common tags like "love, wisdom, hate, loathe, apathy, or knowledge"... BUMMER...

Comment: Phobosophia? misophobia? Adidasophia?

Comment: Sophophobia and phobosophy both get hits on google as real words, but neither is exactly a converse of the concept of philosophy, just the word.

Comment: I don't think the word forming element _phobia_ applies here. I considered it initially, but it implies fear of, as opposed to an established disdain for...

Misophobia would be hate of fear...

Comment: Thank you for your time though... Cheers...

Comment: The word is [*Marcorubian*](https://twitter.com/johnallenpaulos/status/664267801813778437), of course.

Comment: @DanBron haha... That could go viral...

Comment: Isn't *prejudice* the hatred of wisdom?

Comment: 'Philosophy' may be *derived* from 'love of wisdom', but it doesn't *mean* 'love of wisdom' any more. You can ask about words that mean 'hatred of wisdom' but they won't be the converse of *philosophy*.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://english.stackexchange.com/q/245891/105642

Comment: _Sophiphilia_ 'wisdom of love' is a converse. _Philophobia_ is an inverse,

Comment: In modern english, "anti-intellectualism" is the word that communicates this meaning.

Comment: @DJClayworth not sure what you mean by "anymore"... I am curious as to what the word philosophy means now... and since the etymology of philosophy is documented on this site as _love of wisdom_, and my question specifically states that I am in search of the converse of both the word _philosophy_, as well as, the original interpretation _love of wisdom_... why wouldn't our quest produce the converse(s) of "_philosophy_"? Please enlighten us...

Comment: @anemone The intention of this thread and the thread you pointed to are not equivalent... The _other_ thread is in search of a disdain for new knowledge, or I suppose more simply [learning], but that is not what we are exploring... We want to explore that expression to hate/loathe wisdom, not to define what wisdom is, but to simply define this phrase/expression into a single word.

As a side note, it appears to be seeking scientific knowledge, and philosophy is not this. I am not convinced science can produce wisdom. But that is a whole other conversation.

Thanks for your time/effort...

Comment: @John Lawler... I was sure my logic was off in my original question, but didn't want to make this a scholarly exploration, instead more of a thought experiment that suspends logic in favor of the question... Sophiphilia is an interesting word as it is... thanks for that... cheers...

Comment: @JackM You are absolutely right... anti-intellectualism certainly encompasses what I was after... thank you for that... do you think anti-intellectualism has sorta lost it's forza as such a popular culture term? I suppose I am just seeking a word with some presence... thanks again... cheers

Comment: Did you read the definition of 'philosophy' in a dictionary?

Answer (score 15):

Misosophy (μισοσοφία), hatred of wisdom, from μῖσος, hatred, and σοφία, wisdom.  The word
μισόσοφος, hater of wisdom, was used by Plato in the Republic (456a). Cf.
misogyny, hatred of women.

Comment: This is a great start! I agree with, and dig, the word forming element _miso_-... I just wish it rolled off the tongue a bit easier... haha...

Comment: I think I am sold on Misosophy after your thorough argument! It seems to fit the intended expression reasonably, and the use of _miso_- in Plato just seals the deal for me... of course, perhaps more answers will roll in... Thank you for the indepth analysis... Cheers...

Comment: wish I could +1 too... well deserved...

Answer (score 10):

I think that the converse of philosophy is *not* to loathe/hate/be apathetic of philosophy. If we assume that the etymology of the word *philosophy* is "love of wisdom," then its converse would be "hatefulness towards wisdom" or "loathing wisdom." In other words, it's the wisdom that is "not loved," rather than *philosophy* that is "not loved."

With that in mind, at first I would have suggested *ked-* as an ancient Greek word for hate based on its etymological relation to the English word "hate" (with a meaning of care, trouble, sorrow), as seen in the following sources:

> -hate (v.) Old English hatian "regard with extreme ill-will, have a passionate aversion to, treat as an enemy," from Proto-Germanic *haton (cognates: Old Saxon haton, Old Norse hata, German hassen, Gothic hatan "to hate"), from PIE root *kad- "sorrow, hatred" (cognates: Avestan sadra- "grief, sorrow, calamity," Greek kedos "care, trouble, sorrow," Welsh cas "pain, anger"). ([Source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hate))
>
> The etymology of the english term hate is initially traced back to the greek term kedos. The –os is a greek linguistic device that is added to many of the root words in that language. The root of kedos is thus ked. ([Source](http://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/hate/index.html))

Thus, I would expect a word like:

- kedosophy

It's pronounceable, but I've never heard it used. Ever. And, as pointed out in the comments, despite the etymological relationship, *kedos* is not a true translation of *hate*.

But there is hope yet. The opposite of phil- is generally recognized as phob- (even though in my mind, *phob-* is more commonly used to indicate fear). ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-phil-)) So that would give us:

- **phobosophy**

This appears to be a recent construction, but appears to be the intended meaning. ([Source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phobosophy))

> **The fear of abstract knowledge or philosophical thinking; anti-philosophy.**

Another direction is to use the prefix *miso-*, which is listed as an opposite of *philo-* using [this non-authoritative source](http://www.crosswordnexus.com/clue/opposite-of-philo). But it does appear to have the desired meaning, based on its meaning of hatred as listed here.

> Forming compound words having the sense of "hatred of", "dislike of", "contempt for". ([Source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/miso-))

This yields the word:

- **misosophy**

Which means:

> **A hatred of wisdom or knowledge.** ([Source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misosophy))

Interestingly, checking out the ngram ([here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=misosophy%2Cphobosophy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmisosophy%3B%2Cc0)), *misosophy* is used extremely rarely, but *phobosophy* not even listed at all.

As an aside, I have read that the classical opposite of *philosophy* is sophistry, defined as:

> 1. Plausible but fallacious argumentation.
> 2. A plausible but misleading or fallacious argument.  ([Source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sophistry))

But this does NOT appear to be the word that the is being asked for.

Comment: I agree completely with your initial analysis of my comment, and should have been more explicit... To hate/loathe/apathy towards wisdom was my initial intention... 

Although linguistically it is interesting that there could also be a formation to define hate/loathe/apathy towards the love of wisdom, which is a completely different path... The former being sentiments/reaction to the object that is loved (wisdom), and the latter being sentiments/reactions (hate/loathe/apathy) to the converse sentiments/reactions of the object (love)...

Of course, maybe I am just reaching here...

Comment: I don't think -_phobia_- is a good fit for the same reasons you do... it is not necessarily fear...

I considered sophistry, but it is an ambiguous defining term due to the complexity of the school of thought... Perhaps, once again I am reaching, and sophistry is in fact the proper term, but it just doesn't seem to fit seamlessly to the intended expression...

Comment: Thank you for the indepth analysis... And the tags! Cheers...

Comment: The Greek word κῆδος (kēdos) does not mean “hate”, it means “caring, concern with, mourning”. This is a terrible answer.

Comment: @fdb "Kedos" appears to have several meanings; [this link](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hate) indicates that it means (or meant) "care, trouble, sorrow" and is etymologically related to "hate." In any event, thank you for your feedback. While your tone is inappropriate, I will update my answer to make it better.

Comment: Etymology does not define the meaning of a word in a particular language.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia...

> [**philistinism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philistinism) *- describes the social attitude of anti-intellectualism that undervalues and **despises art, beauty, spirituality, and intellect***

I'd say that *art, beauty, spirituality, and intellect* covers most if not all "wisdom", and that *a wise philistine* is oxymoronic.

Comment: I can see your line of thought here @FumbleFingers... it is good, and on the right track, but I am not sure that it fits the model of defining wisdom comprehensively, and the original intent is to find/create the word that does... Thanks for the go though... Cheers

Comment: @socratics: I suppose it depends how you define "wisdom". I've nailed my colours to the mast. What do *you* think it means?

Comment: I totally agree... defining wisdom is in fact the conundrum... Thus far I am sticking to Misosophy, since the root -miso is used in Plato's text (see above)... I am not sure there is a right or wrong answer, but instead each of these may some day become jargon simply because someone used it, and did so properly... Maybe the use of philistinism is simply waiting to be revived, and the way it is used blankets the hate/loathe of wisdom... Time shall tell...

Answer (score 0):

*Philomory* - The love of foolishness.

Comment: Thanks @Chris but I don't think that fits the model of being converse to the original expression... the converse of loving one thing, is not the loving of another...

Answer (score -1):

Rather than a loathing of knowledge, couldn't the opposite be a "loving of ignorance"? I'm trying to find an example, but I can't think of any overt examples (except for silly ones, like "fan of New York Jets").

Comment: Thanks @Adam but I don't think that fits the model of being converse to the original expression... the converse of loving one thing, is not the loving of another...