# A word that means/defines to live a philosophical life[style]?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, philosophy

So this is a continuation of sorts to a thread I started a while ago about *a word that means/defines
 [The Converse of Philosophy](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/286956/147317)... *

The question is... If the etymology of *bio-* is [*Greek bio-, comb. form of bios "one's life, course or way of living, lifetime"*], and philosophy is [*love of wisdom*], then would **biosophy** be a variation that could be used to define/characterize *a life of wisdom*/*living a life of wisdom*?

[*bio-* etymology source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bio-&allowed_in_frame=0)

Comment: "contemplative"

Comment: The prefix "bio-" refers to animal or vegetal life, rather than to the way of life.

Comment: I am not sure we are looking at the same etymology @Graffito...

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bio-&allowed_in_frame=0

Notice it differentiates *animal life* explicitly... not to mention the origin explicitly states that it means *"one's life, course or way of living, lifetime"*... As I stated...

Comment: Etymology is one thing, usage is another: except "biography", I don't see many words with the "bio-" prefix where it means way of life.

Comment: Usage does not dictate the value of existence my friend... And every word in "usage" began with a question like this one... Q.E.D.

Comment: The word "philosopher" refers to a person who lives a life of philosophy. What more could you want?