# commonly used Metaphor, phrase, idiom or colloquialism for people 'who take themselves too seriously'

Tags: idioms

I was thinking about this in context of trophy hunters with the macho posturing and stuff but it needs to apply to anyone who thinks or pretends that what they are doing is very important or dangerous or difficult to do.

I feel like the words are right there in back of my head but can't seem to grab hold of it.

Comment: 'Pretentious' is one description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word for someone who is ignorant and proud?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119199/word-for-someone-who-is-ignorant-and-proud)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. Not exactly! egotist applies there but doesn't exactly apply here.

Comment: @NigelJ. I guess 'pretentious' might be right but doesn't seem to send the right message.

Comment: @LalitJindal 'Highfalutin' is pretty good, I think. Or there's the Glaswegian expression - 'If he was made of chocolate he would eat himself'.

Comment: @NigelJ. That's hilarious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i put in bold those that i remember my lawyer grandfather using:

grandiose, **highfalutin** (also hifalutin), high-minded, la-di-da (also la-de-da or lah-de-dah or lah-dee-dah or lah-di-dah),ostentatious, pompous, snippy airy, **grandiloquent**, high-flown, high-sounding, high-toned, sententious, arrogant, bumptious, complacent, conceited, egoistic (also egoistical), egotistic, high-and-mighty, high-handed, high-hat, **hoity-toity**, imperious, important, overweening, presumptuous, prideful, proud, self-asserting, self-assertive, self-centered, self-complacent, self-conceited, self-important, self-obsessed, self-pleased, self-satisfied, smug, uppity, vain, **vainglorious**

https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/highfalutin

Comment: Yeah 'vainglorious', that's perfect. 'la-di-da' is good too but it seems too old fashioned. It reminds me of that scene in 'Annie Hall'. Lol

Comment: Perhaps, though the word has a rather archaic ring to it.

Answer (score 0):

A saying I’ve often heard is “too big for his boots”, meaning someone thinks they can accomplish things that they actually cannot.

Comment: I wanted to up-vote this for you, but you have not added any reference to prove it is  not just opinion.

Comment: You might add "Too big for his britches"  if you are looking for another phrase.